# Is there a way for me to dynamically write a script to add a domain+user to Microsoft SQL server in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-injection

I have to use this exact script below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CheckIfSQLLoginExistsAndCreateLogin] 
    @SearchDomain NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @SearchUsername NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max);
    DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX);

    IF @SearchUsername != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE [name] =  @Domain\@Username) CREATE LOGIN [@Domain\@Username] FROM WINDOWS';
        SET @params = N'@Username NVARCHAR(MAX), @Domain NVARCHAR(MAX)';
    END
            
    exec sp_executesql @sql, @params, @Username=@SearchUsername, @Domain=@SearchDomain      
END
```

The problem I am having is that every time this SP is called I get the following error:

[image: Error Description]

Using this data: @SearchDomain = OFFICE and @SearchUsername = BJackson

Comment: please use formatted text instead of image

Comment: Whenever issues occur with dynamic SQL, the first thing to do is add `print @sql` and inspect and run the output

Comment: Does this actually work for other parameter values? I have my doubts

Comment: SQL isn't a scripting language, variable names aren't escaped by their values in strings. To object name `[@Domain]` will be treated as the **literal** name `[@Domain]` *not* the name of stored in a variable named `@Domain`.

Comment: Side note: don't use `sp_` for prefixing your object names; the prefix is reserved by Microsoft. Using it comes with a performance penalty and could result in your procedures simply not working one day after an update/upgrade

Comment: Nick.Dermaid yes it does: IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE [name] =  'OFFICE\BJackson') CREATE LOGIN [OFFICE\BJackson] FROM WINDOWS

The above works perfectly.

Comment: @NickWeidemann I doubt that... You have `WHERE [name] =  @Domain\@Username` *not* `WHERE [name] =  '@Domain\@Username'`.

Comment: Using print sql doesn't help me here because I am using a dynamic SP. If I print @sql I will get: 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE [name] =  @Domain\@Username) CREATE LOGIN [@Domain\@Username] FROM WINDOWS'

Comment: What do you mean that doesn't help you... If you `PRINT` the statement and the statement you get isn't what you expect, it's because *your* SQL is wrong...

Comment: Yes Larnu but when the stored proc dynamically adds the paramters, it adds them as text so will look like: .... 'OFFICE'\'BJackson'.

Comment: But they they are **literals**.

Comment: the parameters in `sp_executesql` is only meant for parameter. `sp_executesql` does not perform a find the occurrence of `@Domain` and replace with text

Comment: Because of the way my SP is built, If I PRINT before executing then you don't see the command with the parameters in. If you look at my script can you see I add paramters on the LAST line. If I PRINT before that line (or even after for that matter) it is going to print the SQL command without values in the Parms

Comment: No, you do, @NickWeidemannm because you are *still* thinking parameters are replaced by the values of the parameters. Again, again, again... They are **not**... SQL <> Scripting Language...

Comment: *"Yes Larnu but when the stored proc dynamically adds the paramters, it adds them as text* Wrong...  It doesn't do that at all.

Comment: You shouldn't do this in the first place. Instead use Windows security groups and just add the user to the group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you think SQL is a scripting language; it is *not*.  For example `'@Domain'` means the **literal string** `'@Domain'` *not* replace the literal string `'@Domain'` with the value in the *variable* `@Domain`.

If you have `EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT '@V1 + @V2';', N'@V1 varchar(30), @V2 varchar(30)','This', 'works';` you **don't** get the value `'Thisworks'` you get the value `'@V1 + @V2'` Why? Because they are **literals**.

What you need to do is **safely** inject your parameters for the object names, and *properly* parametrise your `WHERE`:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckIfSQLLoginExistsAndCreateLogin] --removed prefix
    @SearchDomain sysname, --Corrected datatype
    @SearchUsername sysname  --Corrected datatype
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max);
    DECLARE @Login sysname = CONCAT(@SearchDomain,'\',@SearchUsername);

    IF @Login != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE [name] = @Login) CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(Login) + N' FROM WINDOWS';
    END
            
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@Login sysname', @Login;
END;
```

Comment: I see exactly what you mean now with the above example! That CONCAT function sure helps out heaps too.

I think the reason I was so confused is that the previous dev wrote this wrote it very badly within the codebase, so when I tried to create a SP for it - I just copied it as is and tried to parametrize it all.

Thanks for helping me learn a thing @Larnu.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CheckIfSQLLoginExistsAndCreateLogin] 
    @SearchDomain NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @SearchUsername NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max);
    DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX);

  IF @SearchUsername != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE [name] = '''+ @SearchDomain +'\'+ @SearchUsername +''') CREATE LOGIN [@Domain\@Username] FROM WINDOWS';
        SET @params = N'@Username NVARCHAR(MAX), @Domain NVARCHAR(MAX)';
    END
            
    exec sp_executesql @sql, @params, @Username=@SearchUsername, @Domain=@SearchDomain      
END
```